# Images within Emacs. Zoom in and out?

Tags: emacs, zooming

When I open a PNG file in Emacs, I can navigate it using <kbd>C-n</kbd>, <kbd>C-p</kbd>, <kbd>C-f</kbd> and <kbd>C-b</kbd>, but how can I zoom in and out? I couldn't find anything here.

Ideally I would like to bind <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in and out. Any pointers on this swould be great.

Comment: It seems that this is a missing Emacs feature. Consider requesting it, via `M-x report-emacs-bug` (that is also for enhancement requests).

Comment: I've filed that [***enhancement request***](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17119).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I introduce [`image+`](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-imagex).
Usage from elisp file:

```
;;; Usage:

;; * To manupulate a image under cursor.
;;
;;  M-x imagex-global-sticky-mode
;;
;; * C-c + / C-c -: Zoom in/out image.
;; * C-c M-m: Adjust image to current frame size.
;; * C-c C-x C-s: Save current image.
;;
;; * Adjusted image when open image file.
;;
;;  M-x imagex-auto-adjust-mode
```

Comment: Thanks! - Do you have the package on ELPA / MELPA by any chance?

Comment: This package is available on MELPA.

Comment: I just installed `image+` via MELPA (`M-x list-packages`) and the zoom feature is working for me. It is bound to `C-c + / C-c -`, although you have to press that combo for each level of zoom - there is no built-in shortcut for multiple zoom levels.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of doing it (e.g. `C-x C-+` doesn't work), but you could try eimp (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsImageManipulation) -- I haven't tried it myself though..

Comment: Thanks - interestingly Emacs' PDF viewer does support zooming in an out (with + and -), but not the PNG viewer...